# Facebook API to post on Pages without Oauth

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

Does Facebook provide an API to post to a Facebook page without using Oauth?

For example, if someone submits something on my website, I want to automatically post to my Facebook page mentioning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you'll need an active access token for the page in order to make such posts; have one of the admins grant your app the manage_pages permission and obtain a page access token for the page - store this in your code and use that to make the updates.
When it expires, have the admin come back to your app and you can retrieve a new token

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/ has the full info

Comment: Thanks for that. Well I guess when I go to approve the submissions, I can Oauth myself and when I approve something, it posts to my Facebook page. Seems like the only way.

Comment: How do you actually use the static access token in the app??

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application, you can skip the per user authentication and just do it with your application's token.

Please see:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

"I want to automatically post to my Facebook page mentioning it." You may have to have your app use YOUR authentication to post to your wall/page.

Comment: This won't work, to post as a page you'll need an access token for the page, which needs one of the page admins to go through the oauth flow

Answer (score 0):

Coracast has an API that essentially lets you do this, you can post to their API with simple form post/get requests and then they push to Facebook from their side.